# VBA/SQL: How to build SQL with Function in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a case in which I am trying to pull the state value from a description field. However, I need to change some columns depending on the state. So here is what I have

Description Example: Management EXECUTIVE CTJACKSONVILLE.FL.32216-4041

```
Function getState(description As String) As String
    Dim s() As String
    s = Split(description, ".")
    getState = s(UBound(s) - 1)
End Function
```

I want to change some columns depending on if it returns a correct State abbreviation or not. If the value does not return a valid state I want to flag the invoice. So something like this...

```
UPDATE tblInvoices
SET [Invoice Flag] = True
Where getState(description) <> ValidStates.Abbreviation
```

Something along those lines. Sorry for the newbie-ness. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a function called `isValidState()` that returns a boolean

```
Function isValidState(st As String) As Boolean
    Select Case st
        Case "AL", "FL", "NY" ...
            isValidState = True
        Case Else
            isValidState = False
    End Select
End Function
```

Another way could be is to have a table with all the state codes (Let's call it `MyStateTable`)

```
Function isValidState(st As String) As Boolean
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("MyStateTable")
    rs.FindFirst ("StateFieldName = '" & st & "'")
    If rs.NoMatch Then
        isValidState = False
    Else
        isValidState = True
    End If
    rs.Close
End Function
```

So your query will look something like

```
UPDATE tblInvoices
SET [Invoice Flag] = True
Where isValidState(getState(description)) = True
```

Edit:

```
Function getState(description As String) As String
    Dim s() As String
    s = Split(description, ".")
    If (UBound(s) > 1) then
        getState = s(UBound(s) - 1)
    Else
        getState = vbNullString 'Or change this to "" or something else that makes sense for your usage'
    End if
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry - so how would I put this in to the SQL Query where I need to change the Invoice Flag to True? I guess my question is, how do I combine running the function inside a SQL query?

Comment: Sorry, having one last problem: Since I haven't run a function - I'm not sure what needs to be quoted and such in Access. I keep getting an error: "Compile Error: Expected Expression"... Not sure where I need the quotes and &
    
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Processing " & _
    "SET [Comments] = 'Review All PO Lines. Ship To State Cannot be Determined.', [Invoice Flag] = True" & _
    "WHERE " & isValidState(getState(&"[Inv Description]"&))

Comment: Nevermind - Now I'm having a problem with isValidState. For rs.FindFirst ("StateFieldName = '" & st & "'") I am returning "Operation is not supported for this type of object"

Comment: Think you need a space between the `True` and `WHERE`.  A good way to check your SQL strings is to place a breakpoint on the line of code you want to check then in your Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) you can type in `?<your expression` and you can see the result.  E.g. `?1+1` will return `2`, so in your case of SQL you'd have something like `?"UPDATE ......." & "..." etc

Comment: Try `Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("MyStateTable",dbOpenSnapshot)` and if that doesn't work try `Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("MyStateTable", dbOpenDynaset)`

Comment: Ok - now this is a little odd. That seemed to work, except it keeps looping back through the GetState Function. It runs through successfully once, then it keeps running multiple times through getState before running into a Subscript out of Range error on getState = s(UBound(s) -1) Is it running over and over on the same string? Shouldn't it be changing to the next Row of data every time?

Comment: That might be occurring on a string that doesn't have any `.` in it.  If that is the case then `Split()` will return a 0 size array and then `UBound(s) - 1` to -1.  I'm adding a modified `getState` function in my answer

Comment: You, good sir, are a Gentleman and a Scholar. <3 

Thank you so much for your time and help. Hopefully I can get better situated to not have to ask so many simple questions.

Comment: Very odd, the code runs correctly, loops through all the descriptions successfully, except at the very end It gets a Datatype mismatch in criteria expression on the SQL Query - and it doesn't point to anything in particular... I'm honestly at a loss.